# Why are Sensor values so different across devices?

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors

I'm currently using android devices to develop an application that uses sensor values to get information about the environment. I'm using a Samsung S6 Edge and a Nexus 7 tablet and the sensor values i get from the devices are very different.

One example:
[image: Gyroscope Values from 2 Devices]

These are the Gyroscope values (x-axis) from both devices sitting still on a table. This is one of the best in values similarity, most of them are not even close.

A couple of the bad value similarities:

Magnetic Field:
[image]

Accelerometer:
[image]

I'm wondering why values are so different across devices?

Thanks.

Comment: if I'm right, then that are too small values (0.001 - 0.002). BTW, what is the unit of those numbers? is it G? m/c2? or what? As for me those differences are just fine as they are very small. Device sensors aren't suitable for accurate measurements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm wondering why values are so different across devices?

They are not particularly different. Those are values in radians/second, where a "360-degree turn" is ~6.28 radians. Your values range from ~-0.002 to +0.004. ~0.004 radians/s is ~0.229 degrees/s. This is **tiny**. IOW, your values are all similar to 0.

Plus, as [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html) states:

> In practice, the gyroscope noise and offset will introduce some errors which need to be compensated for. This is usually done using the information from other sensors, but is beyond the scope of this document.

More generally, different hardware will have different sensors from different manufacturers.

With respect to accelerometer, again, your values are tiny. Earth's gravity is 9.8 m/s<sup>2</sup>; your values are between ~0.15 and ~-0.05.

With respect to magnetic field... your Samsung seems messed up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I suppose using the good values was a bad way to propose the question. I've added mag field and accelerometer. Mag field is one that is way off.

Comment: @Waddas: See updated answer. This is one of the reasons why apps sometimes ask users to "calibrate" various sensors (e.g., rotate the device along each axis in turn), so you can get a sense of what value range makes sense for you. But, this is also one of the reasons why I don't work much with Android's sensor suite... :-)

Comment: A calibration method does seem to be required but unfortunately that's not feasible with my application. I guess there's a long way to go in terms of heterogeneity in computing.